# How to compile 1 dll from github repository?

Tags: api

trying to use the library but can't install it like a complete newbie how to do it
example documetation tweetinvi. I also tried to compile 1 dll from the repository, but it immediately produces 50+ pieces. Is it possible to compile a repository into 1 dll with all envy?
How do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0EDv.png)

I can't figure out what to do